# Should unauthorized actions in the UI be hidden, disabled, or result in an error?

Tags: user-interface, authorization

This is a perennial question for me that I've never really resolved so I'd like your input.  If I have actions that I know a user will not be able to perform due to insufficient privileges or object state, should the UI elements for those actions be hidden from the user, visible but disabled, or visible and result in an error if attempted? What would be the rationale for your answer? If disabled, would you communicate the reason why and, if so, how?

This is a web interface so I already know that I need to check the incoming post/get for permissions and handle errors there anyway.  I'm primarily talking about how to handle the UI.

This is similar to [Rules about disabling or hiding menu items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79033/rules-about-disabling-or-hiding-menu-items), though I am interested in all types of UI elements not just menus.

Examples:

1. I have a New page that allows a user to create a new Event.  Events can be master events or subevents.  Creating a master event requires "EditMasterEvent" privilege, while creating a subevent requires only "EditEvent" privilege.  I have a drop down that allows one to choose an existing event as the parent (master event) or no parent (this is a master event).  Should the "Create Master Event" choice be shown on the dropdown or omitted if the user only has "EditEvent" privileges.
2. Deleting events requires that you be an application administrator or have the appropriate edit permission for the event type.  In the latter case, the event must also be more than 5 years old.  Deleting an event causes major cascading deletes of related data in the system and for legal reasons this data must be kept for at least 5 years after the event.  Since this operation is rare for the normal user, the typical case is that the action is not available.  Should it be shown always or only when actually possible?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As with nearly all UI questions, the answer is  "it depends".

You need to weigh discoverability with user satisfaction, among other things. For example, allowing an invalid action gives you an opportunity to explain why something is invalid. This is particularly useful if the answer to "why is this disabled" isn't obvious.  For an application where most users are beginners, that's important.

On the other hand, it can be mightily frustrating to see a control, click on it, only to be rewarded with a "sorry, you can't do that now" message. An app I inherited a couple years back was rife with that sort of stuff and it made using the UI an exercise in frustration.

Completely hiding functionality is probably rarely a good idea. Imagine knowing some feature "was there a minute ago" but now it's gone. Whether it's a menu item or a toolbar button or something else entirely, making it hidden can be an exercise in frustration for the end user.

Try doing a little usability testing, if only by asking the next person you see "hey, does it make sense to disable this or show you an informative dialog". Just one other opinion is often enough to get you to look at the problem from another direction.

Bottom line: do what best serves the user. All the scenarios you mention are valid under certain circumstances. As with all UI questions, ask yourself (or better, your users) what best serves their needs.

Comment: Good answer. I disagree a bit with the hiding. Of course, in the context you mention (hide operations that are normally visible), it's a frustrating choice to hide them, but things never available (see Stephen C.'s Answer) should never be visible. Also, if there are any operations certain groups of users (that your application doesn't differentiate internally) will never use, there should be the option to hide these entirely.

Answer (score 51):

Hidden - This is the best approach for actions that are never available to the current user. There is no point in having the user waste mental effort figuring out why something is disabled if there is no action they can take to change this.

Disabled - This is the best approach for actions that are sometimes available, but not at the moment or in the current context. A disabled option should convey two things: first, the action is not available right now, and second, there is something the user could do to make the action available (change some setting or permission, select an item, enter prerequisite data, etc.). If you can indicate what needs to be done to enable the action in a tooltip - all the better. Enabling/disabling actions as the user enters data or changes context provides excellent feedback about what the program requires.

Fail with an Error - This is the worst choice. You should only resort to an error report for operations that might work: you can't tell that it will fail except by trying.

Comment: > If you can indicate what needs to be done to enable the action in a tooltip.

Isn't that effectively displaying an error message, or as you said, fail with an error? I see a component, I click on it, I fail - it shows an error (indicates what needs to be done).

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov The key difference is whether you already know the operation will inevitably fail,  in which case it should be disabled,  or it might succeed, and you can only know by actually attempting it (common if the action involves some external system).

Comment: Then the question matters only when we don't already know the operation will inevitably fail. Otherwise, more important question is why the button is in the codebase at all (knowing truly is only possible at compile time, in runtime it is just possibilities). My perspective is that if you want a user to know that an action is possible but just not for them - show it and display an error (pop up, whatever) when acted upon. So many examples are there, even on stackoverflow - unauthenticated users can still see voting or reporting buttons yet they have to authorize to use them. Hide otherwise.

Answer (score 13):

I disable the elements instead of hiding them. That way the user knows the option would normally be available, and I provide a tooltip to explain why the element isn't currently available.

Comment: Do you do this when the user would never have the ability to invoke the action?  That is, the action requires "DeletePermission" which the user does not have so they would never be able to execute it?

Comment: Good point - I would usually hide it in that case. Sometimes it's a good idea not to promote functionality you don't want the user to be aware of. :)

Comment: Don't forget the tooltip! There's nothing more annoying than seeing the option you want sitting right there, but grayed out with no explanation.

Comment: I think this answer is too general, and doesn't apply to all situations.  It depends a lot on what the purpose of the control is, how knowledgeable the user is (or isn't), and a whole host of factors.

Answer (score 5):

It depends. Do you want the user to be aware that the action is possible, just not for them? In that case, show them the button, but disable it. An example might be if a user doesn't have delete authority, but other users do, they should know that entries CAN be deleted, so they can ask someone to do it for them if they need the action.

On the other hand, if the user is not supposed to even know about the action (for example, a user who does not have read access to audit logs probably shouldn't know that these logs exist) should not be able to see the button, so hide it completely.

Comment: I like the idea of leaving it available when you are ok with the user knowing that it can be done, just not by them.

Answer (score 3):

Great question!

A couple of considerations:

If you place the elements on the page but disable them, there's still a remote chance that the user could doctor the system and enable them using a javascriptlet.

If you do not show them at all, the overall functionality may be a bit confusing to the general user.  "Shouldn't there be an edit button here?"

If you're going to either display and disable or display and verify the elements, I would **definitely** do server-side validation.  Don't leave the validation in the hands of JavaScript; I think the reasons for this are obvious.

Comment: Right.  I always do server-side validation both of data and permissions.

Comment: Even if you would hide the controls completely there is still a chance an advanced user makes the feature available to them if not server validation is performed...

Answer (score 3):

I tend to handle the two different types of situations differently.  Is this an action that is governed by privilege and by state of the object.

If the person does not have enough privileges to do an action, I hide the option, they do not know they can perform the action.

If the option is not available because the object is not in a state that can use that option, I disable it, allowing the option to be visible to the user, but no action can be done.

From your examples:

1. I would not have "Create Master Event" as an option.  The user has insufficient privileges to view it.
2. I would have the Delete button visible to the administrators.  Then depending on how you do the rest of the site (a lot of visible text, tooltips, help icon, etc) I would follow that convention about informing the user why the button is not usable at this time.  And possibly putting a timer on, above, near the button with either how old the post is or how long until it can be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the item, we will either hide them or disable them.  If the user has access to a large feature, but not to a smaller piece inside it, then we will hide the smaller piece.  However, if the user has access to several large features, but not to others, we'll leave them visible but disabled as a marketing ploy to remind them that the features are available for purchase if they should decide they want them.

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen some programs that disable the menu item and change the text of it to "Log in to do blah..."

I like this because it doesn't leave me with the "why isn't this working?" feeling and tells me immediately what to do to get it working.  Not applicable in every case, but this is a nice approach if you can implement it.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is use disabling if the user can do something in the UI to get the privilege. Disabled means “you can do this command, but just not right now the way things are.” The “way things are” includes the current selection, so use enabling/disabling if the user has the EditEvent privilege for old objects but not for new objects. There should be a clear indication which objects are delete-able so users understand why the associated commands are disabled for some objects (e.g., if users generally know that records must be kept for 5 years, a simple Age field maybe be sufficient, perhaps reinforced with a graphic difference for records over 5 years old).

Use message boxes instead of disabling if there is no way to make the reason for the disabling clear to the user assuming they have average knowledge of the domain. Tooltips for disabled controls, BTW, are a great idea, but may not be sufficient by themselves.

Use hiding if the user never has the privilege no matter what they do in the UI given their current position in the organization (e.g., they are not an Application Administrator). It is cluttering and frustrating to use disabling or message boxes for this case. As far as the users are concerned, actions they don’t have the privilege for are not their job (otherwise they’d have the privilege), and so the associated controls should simply not exist in their UI. Documentation or organization procedure manuals may tell users how such actions are accomplished (e.g., “Your supervisor creates new events for you.”).

I’ve more details at http://www.zuschlogin.com/?p=40.

Answer (score 1):

I would say disable with a hover containing the reason.

It prevents the user from wondering what the hell is going on while at the same time letting them know certain actions are possible under the right conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a particular hatred of applications that disable buttons. If you're an end user - you want to know why you can't use that button. Having it greyed out doesn't tell you anything. How do you get to the state to enable it? Tooltips are one solution, but they aren't the best, a lot of users will struggle with tooltips (unless you're working with experienced users).

Comment: Of course, this depends a lot on context. For example, if you have a "play" and "stop" button, it's pretty obvious why one is disabled when the other is enabled. Seeing them toggle as you press them quickly teaches you their behavior. Not all "why is this diabled" questions are so easily answered.

Comment: Also, consider the fact that sometimes the eye will perceive a particular combination of enabled and disabled features as a clue to the state of the program. You can use this to the user's advantage. It all depends on the users, their goals, and the richness (or lack thereof) of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

My personal feeling is that the elements should always be present. If the user doesn't have enough permissions to do them, they should generate an error when clicked upon.

I know that translators don't really enjoy creating a zillion different "permission denied" error messages, so this is often not done in localised applications, which tend to hide the elements instead.

In practice a lot of people tend to hide the options instead even in non-localised apps.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have provided good answers with valid suggestion to avoid hiding elements and instead disable them and provide some hints for the reasons.

So, I would like to look at it from different perspective - but how to hide some UI elements in cases when user does not need to see them, no matter if he has or has no permissions for particular actions related to the elements?

For example, let's say, users of some role are given access to sellers records in the system.

But then business analyst says: "Look, there is a dropdown with sellers list in this form and we should not allow some specific roles to see it".

Developer asks: "So, we just remove the "Read sellers" permission from this role, right?" But the analyst replies: "No! This role should still be able to view the sellers on the Sellers page. It's just this single form where we should hide the list for some roles and show it to some other roles."

So, the developer adds permission called "Show sellers dropdown on the form X".

Ooops, now we have a problem. Access to the same data is being controlled by two separate permissions. Now we have to figure out how to combine both of them. And what if there are more than one form where seller's list should be hidden for some roles? How do we combine it with "Read seller's list"? For us, developers, it is somewhat clear that "Read" permission should have higher priority above "View", so even if a user can "View" a list, he still should not see it (or see empty or disabled with a helpful hint) if he does not have "Read" permission. We, developers and analysts of the system know it. But how should the system administrator know it? Should we teach him this? How can we guarantee that the admin won't confuse all those "View" and "Read" for the single data list?

As you see, it all gets messy for one reason - we are mixing data processing permissions with UI conveniences in the list of role permissions.

I have seen many projects where it gets messy because permissions on the server side get coupled too much to UI, which asks for troubles and possible security holes (because you have multiple items in your role permission editor for the same actions on the same data).

Permissions are about access and operations on some specific data. UI can only react to permissions in consistent way throughout entire system (disabling with hints, hiding etc.). We should never invent new permission entries just for UI purposes.

Now the question remains - but how do we actually hide UI elements for some system users to avoid overwhelming them with huge amount of always disabled items? One solution might be role workspaces. If we clearly know that users of some role will never ever need access to some specific data, we create a set of UI control entries, similar to permissions, but this time we don't call them permissions. And we can get really fancy here, even allowing users themselves to freely customize their workspace and choose what they can or cannot see. Of course, permissions will always take the highest priority, but it will only affect the data and state of UI elements and not visibility.

That's my two cents. Unfortunately, I myself haven't worked on such a system where permissions and UI workspace options are neatly separated because I always somehow come too late to a project, when the "damage has been done". But I hope some day I'll have a chance. I just hope to find a good example how to do this right, but somehow internet searches do not give me anything useful. Does it really mean that nobody else has came to the same conclusions as me? I don't believe it, somebody in the enterprise design pattern world should have noticed this UI<->permission impedance mismatch long ago.

Comment: Seems like you are conflating role, permission, and authorization. A role is a classification of the user. A permission is the ability to do something. An authorization is the application of a permission to a role for an activity. In your example, I wouldn't create a new permission for the role, I'd simply apply a different permission for that role to the new activity - i.e. you're authorized to read the sellers list on form Y but not on form X. That would probably involve adding a different action to retrieve the sellers list for form X so that you can apply a separate authorization.

Comment: @tvanfosson - " you're authorized to read the sellers list on form Y but not on form X" - unfortunately in many cases it's not about authorization; it is just for user's convenience; just to avoid cluttering his workspace with unneeded UI elements. User him/herself even could freely add the elements back, if for some reason they are needed, thus creating a customized workspace. But as many systems do not have a concept of such workspaces, they tend to just mix it all in a huge "permissions" list to apply authorizations, as you say.